# Ajax gives 400 error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax, widgets

Basically I am trying to fire an ajax call in an Elementor widget.

So I have a button on the click it executes a function in the widget class.
To elementor basic template I have added this.

```
  public function __construct( $data = [], $args = null ) {
        parent::__construct( $data, $args );
        //add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'pgggo_ajax_loader_callback' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_pgggo_ajax_loader', array( $this, 'pgggo_ajax_loader_callback' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pgggo_ajax_loader', array( $this, 'pgggo_ajax_loader_callback' ) );
        //add_action( 'elementor/ajax/register_actions', 'pgggo_ajax_loader_callback');
    }

public function pgggo_ajax_loader_callback(){
      echo "okaycool";
    }
```

this my javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#pgggo-sort-filter-form').on('click', '.icon-box', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(pgggoAjax);
      $.ajax({
        url: pgggoAjax.ajax_url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          'action': 'pgggo_ajax_loader',
          'nonce' : pgggoAjax.nonce
        },
        success: function (response) {
          //alert("somethingwrong");
          console.log(response);
          $('#pgggo-ajax-output').append(response);
                      },
    });
  });
});
```

but I get 400 errors every time.`console.log(pgggoAjax);` this returns correctly but the function does n't seem to execute. Is it impossible to add ajax functionality to elementor widget?

Comment: You can’t hook AJAX callbacks inside a widget constructor. It doesn’t make any sense to. Widgets are not loaded during AJAX requests.

Comment: @JacobPeattie oh I see. Any workaround?  I am trying this way because I need to have the data specific( that lies in that in this specific widget class) to the widget in ajax callback function.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The only data an AJAX callback has access to is what you send it. You probably need to restructure your code. The AJAX callback should be independent of the widget, and any widget-specific information should be sent to it with the AJAX request.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for letting me know that I am on wrong track. Still no idea of how to make it work. Let me try something else

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to fire this action on the front-end or in the Elementor editor or something else? Also post your full code. It is possible to do, but just trying to understand your objective a bit better.

Comment: @Adam In both front end as well as editor(if it's possible in here too that will be awesome)..I have a post grid widget I want to implement ajax functionality to it. It has a frontend sort and filer..with ajax I want to load posts.But the widget specific data is needed to output ..i am unable to figure it out :|

Comment: @Adam Hi, is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The issue you are likely facing is that you are trying to add your ajax actions from within the widget itself that may be instantiated on the `elementor/widgets/widgets_registered` hook.

If so, this is hook `elementor/widgets/widgets_registered` is too late and `do_action( "wp_ajax_{$action}" )` and `do_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}" )` have already fired.

#### Working example:

**NOTE: very rough and not thoroughly abstracted, which I will leave to you, this code however exemplifies creating a widget that outputs a button that when clicked, calls a callback, then appends a result to the target element, in this case "Hello World!"**

Create a plugin with the following three files:

- plugin.php
- widget.php
- script.php

**plugin.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Elementor Widget
 * Plugin URI:  https://example.com
 * Description: Custom Elementor Widget
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      WordPress StackExchange
 * Author URI:  https://example.com
 */

final class Elementor_Custom_Extension
{
    private static $_instance = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('plugins_loaded', [$this, 'init']);
    }

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public static function dir_path($path = '')
    {
        return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . $path;
    }

    public static function dir_url($path = '')
    {
        return plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . $path;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        add_action('elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [$this, 'widget_init']);
        add_action('elementor/frontend/after_register_scripts', [$this, 'widget_scripts']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_pgggo_widget', [$this,  'widget_callback']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pgggo_widget', [$this,  'widget_callback']);
    }

    public function widget_callback()
    {
        wp_send_json_success([
            'message' => 'Hello World!'
        ]);
    }

    public function widget_scripts()
    {
        $script_url  = Elementor_Custom_Extension::dir_url('script.js');
        $script_path = Elementor_Custom_Extension::dir_path('script.js');

        wp_register_script('pgggo_widget', $script_url, ['jquery'], filectime($script_path));
        wp_localize_script('pgggo_widget', 'pgggo_widget_vars', [
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
            'ajax_action' => 'pgggo_widget',
        ]);
    }

    public function widget_init()
    {
        require_once(__DIR__ . '/widget.php');

        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type(
            new Elementor_Custom_Widget()
        );
    }
}

Elementor_Custom_Extension::instance();
```

**widget.php**

```
<?php

class Elementor_Custom_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {
    public function get_name() {
        return 'pgggo_widget';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'My Custom Widget', 'pgggo_widget' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'fa fa-code';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'general' ];
    }

    protected function _register_controls() {
        // add your controls
    }

    protected function render() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'pgggo_widget' );

        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

        ?>

        <div id="my-custom-widget">

            <button>Click Me</button>

            <div class="target">

            </div>
        </div>

        <?php

    }
}
```

**script.js**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#my-custom-widget').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: pgggo_widget_vars.ajax_url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
            'action': pgggo_widget_vars.ajax_action,
            // 'nonce' : // do your nonce here...
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#my-custom-widget .target').append(response.data.message);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

#### Update:

In relation to comment your [518351](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355238/ajax-gives-400-error/355245?noredirect=1#comment518351_355245)

> if you notice there is a problem widget_callback() in plugin.php will not have access to widget.php $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display() so it will not be able to get the data for that specific widget

If you need to pass data to the back-end from the front-end via AJAX, you need to make the data accessible to your AJAX handler. To do so you can add a call to `wp_localize_script` in your widget `render()` method that localises the the data.

Example:

```
protected function render() {

    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

    wp_enqueue_script( 'pgggo_widget' );

    // make data accessible on the JavaScript variable "pgggo_widget_settings"
    wp_localize_script( 'pgggo_widget', 'pgggo_widget_settings', [
        'settings' => $settings
    ] );

    // etc...
}
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```js
var settings = pgggo_widget_settings.settings;
console.log(settings.some_property);
```

**WARNING!**

In the example above I am passing the entire settings object to the `wp_localize_script` function call. You may NOT want to do this for security purposes in the event you have any sensitive information in your settings that you don't want exposed. In that case, be sure to selectively push data from the `$this->get_settings_for_display()` method call onto your local variable.

Comment: Thank you. if you notice there is a problem `widget_callback()` in `plugin.php` will not have access to  `widget.php`  `$settings = $this->get_settings_for_display()` so it will not be able to get the data for that specific widget

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla see the update portion of the answer for getting data out of your settings.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will add a bounty to this

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla that's ok mate, I appreciate the gesture but no need to do so. We are here to help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. there is problem, enueque and localize script in the render() function will not work.

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla can you elaborate? Do you see the `pgggo_widget_settings` variable in your source when inspecting it? Are you running caching plugins? Do you have debugging enabled and are there any notices in your logs? E.g. see https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: Hi, I tried to solve it. Came up with some methods. https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/adding-javascript-to-elementor-widgets/  I am close to my answer but still not yet been able to pass the `$this->get_settings_for_display()` to the constructor. I came to know that enqueuing therein render() will not work. any ideas?

Comment: Strangely it started working. no idea what's going on

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla great to hear... I did re-test my code yesterday to confirm (it works as expected) but did not have chance to come on and comment. There can be many reasons why it did not work on your end initially, such as another plugin, theme or third-party code interfering. Commonly it can be related to caching plugins (but not always). Thank you for the bounty.